# Which pronunciation is more prevalent; /ə/ or /ӕ/?

Tags: pronunciation

> **a**t hearing one h**a**s got a fortune . . . **a**t last . . . whom I h**a**d never heard . . . **a**t a table . . . (Jane Eyre)

If Jim Dale (who reads the Harry Potter series) had read Jane Eyre, I think he would have pronounced all the **a** sounds as schwa **/ə/**; yet a recording on Librivox.org has the **/ӕ/** sounds. The former is more natural while the latter more punctual. After hearing the audio book, I wonder which pronunciation is more common. Would you let me know?

Comment: What is your question? If your question is how to pronounce a particular word, then what does the dictionary say the pronunciation of that word is? If the question is "is the sound /ə/ or /ӕ/ more common in the general case", this question is probably off topic for ELL.

Comment: This is a legitimate question about *how do people enunciate literature*. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost What do you hope to accomplish by re-opening a 2 year old question with an accepted answer? I don't really follow what's going on here. There are plenty of good or "legitimate" questions that aren't particularly useful for ELL, and this one in particular doesn't seem to have received much attention from learners.

Comment: @ColleenV The reopen vote was prompted by [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/conversation/reopening-which-pronunciation-is-more-prevalent--or-), I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purely functional words are never stressed, and thus are subject to vowel-reduction into schwas.

Comment: +1 But *never* seems a little strong: *Oh, so you **have** got it after all.*

Comment: @StoneyB But in that case it has an additional sense beyond the purely functional, doesn’t it?

Comment: Does it? I'd say it has an additional *function* (viz to bear the stress), but no new sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if accent is important in your query, but I would suggest that the /ə/ would be more common, as noted by [American Accent](http://pages.citebite.com/a1f3s6e4o2xpt).

Comment: It is.  I've used an online service called CiteBite that takes you directly to the entry in the dictionary in order to facilitate reader's ability to quickly locate the entry.  Try clicking on it and you'll see what I mean.  I am in no way shape or form affiliated with either the dictionary or with CiteBite.

Comment: Hmph.  You're right.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I believe M-W is referring to American Accent at some point on their site.  I've updated the reference in my response.